# Regarding arraylist add() return type

Tags: java

This looks like pretty simple.

We know that boolean is the return type of add in`arraylist`. I understand this will return when element got added.
I am looking for scenario when it will return false.

Comment: From the [`ArrayList:add` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)): "***Returns:** `true` (as specified by [`Collection.add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)))*"

Comment: Turing85 so it will always return true.. never false? what do you think

Comment: Not until you extend `ArrayList` and override `add`.

Comment: sure thanks Tom and   Turing85 . iT make sense.

Answer (score 2):

From the [`ArrayList:add` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)):

> **Returns:** `true` (as specified by [`Collection.add(E)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)))

This method will always return `true`.

One could, of course, write something like

```
... = new ArrayList<Whatever>() {
    public void add(Whatever w) {
        super.add(w);
        return false;
    }
};
```

But that is not an `ArrayList` anymore (it is an anonymous class, extending `ArrayList`) and would violate the contract of `Collection::add`.

Comment: Upvoted..so it will always return true.. never false? what do you think

Comment: I extended my answer by an "anti-example". Hope that clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

Java is open-source, you can check the implementation.
For example, Java7 (I just searched for **github arraylist.java**), https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java

```
/**
 * Appends the specified element to the end of this list.
 *
 * @param e element to be appended to this list
 * @return <tt>true</tt> (as specified by {@link Collection#add})
 */
public boolean add(E e) {
    ensureCapacityInternal(size + 1);  // Increments modCount!!
    elementData[size++] = e;
    return true;
}
```

So, it will not return `false`, ever.

Comment: saw already..but was wondering is it  always true. just thought to take opinions of experts

Comment: @spandey15 that is always true, and the result is always `true`. Remember that the operation comes from [`Collection.add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E)), and for example attempting to `add()` an element to a `Set` can return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

As per the `boolean add​(E e)`contract:

The add operation returns `true`

- if this collection changed as a result of the call

The `ArrayList` allows `null` and `duplicates`. so it throw an exception rather returning `false` if unable to add element. See details [add](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#add(E))